# Cant find aspx.cs in jetbrains rider

Tags: c#, asp.net, rider

I have installed Jetbrains Rider and created an ASP.NET Project, but I can't find the behind code of web page.aspx any help?

Rider screenshot:
[Rider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mGa3.png)

Visual Studio screenshot:
[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yICbZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've found to add the code behind is go into the top level form file, place your cursor in the first line, and then click the hammer icon. One of the options will be to create a code behind file. Unsure if there's a less hinky way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYsGJ.jpg

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated my post and added two different screenshots from rider and visual studio.
You are right, in rider the file by default is Razor view, but I can add my own page form (aspx) there's a way to access the behind code? If it doesn't work, how can I do it in Razor view?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect a workaround I discovered to at least get the code behind file created (and update the form). Is that useful at all? I personally stopped working with that before I switched to Rider, so apologies for not being more helpful.