# ASP .net form -- Rider

Tags: c#, asp.net, rider

I'm working with Rider jetBrains ASP.net , I have problems in this form even if this is the way to do it and it work for a lot of people , it's like the .aspx is not attached to his .aspx.cs .

Errors :
1 - in Inherits="Admin"   :  Ambiguous reference 
2 -  name.Focus(); 'name' is undeffined in .aspx.cs and Button1_Click method is not defined in .aspx file ,Like there is no relation between those files even if I see in too many tutorials using this method and it works.

Admin.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="or.master" CodeFile="Admin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin" %>  


<asp:Content ID="test" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">  
            <div align="center">
                  <form id="form1" runat="server">
                        Connection de l'administrateur general
                  <table style="margin: 20px">
                        <tr>
                              <th>Login de l'administrateur</th>
                              <th><asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                        </tr>
                         <tr>
                               <th>Mot de passe</th>
                               <th><asp:TextBox ID="pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></th>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                               <th></th>
                               <th><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Valider" /></th>
                         </tr>
                  </table>
                  </form>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Admin.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using   System.Collections;
using  System.Configuration;
using  System.Data;
using  System.Web;
using  System.Web.Security;
using  System.Web.UI;
using  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using   System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using  System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

public partial class Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name.Focus(); 
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: A similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960999/cant-find-aspx-cs-in-jetbrains-rider

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `name.Focus()`?

Comment: Do you have a 2nd Admin class anywhere else in your project?